# How can I convert the 64 bit timestamp returned from elasticsearch into a datetime in python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

My date histogram query returns something like this:

```
"facets": {
  "hist": {
     "_type": "date_histogram",
     "entries": [
        {
           "time": 1385856000000,
           "count": 1884
        },
        {
           "time": 1385942400000,
           "count": 1902
        },
```

How can I take that time value and get a date string: '2014-02-16'?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def getFiletime(dt):
    microseconds = int(dt) / 10
    seconds, microseconds = divmod(microseconds, 1000000)
    days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 86400)
    return datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days, seconds, microseconds)
```

I get back:

```
1601-01-02 14:37:23.520000
1601-01-02 14:37:32.160000
1601-01-02 14:37:40.800000
1601-01-02 14:37:49.440000
1601-01-02 14:37:58.080000
1601-01-02 14:38:06.720000
1601-01-02 14:38:15.360000
```

Any ideas? I just copied the getFiletime function from the internet. I don't think it's meant for what I'm doing, but I know it's on the right track. I tried putting the "format" specifier in my elastic search query but that doesn't return the timestamp as a string like the documentation states. Any help would be appreciated and thank you for reading!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13181415/538284

Comment: I just tried that and no help, but thank you anyway.

Comment: these aren't 64bit timestamps, just regular (unix epoch) ones with millisecond resolution: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1385942400000 / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` gives `2013-12-02`

Comment: Thank you! That works. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same challenge and created this method to solve the same problem.

```
def to_es_date(d):
    s = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.')
    s += '%03d' % int(round(d.microsecond / 1000.0))
    s += d.strftime('%z')
    return s
```

It takes a datetime with or without timezone, and returns a string that is recognized by ElasticSearch (v1.1.1 for sure).  I'm not sure if the padding is required or not, but it seemed prudent.

```
In [5]: from datetime import datetime

In [6]: import pytz

In [7]: %paste
def to_es_date(d):
        s = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.')
        s += '%03d' % int(round(d.microsecond / 1000.0))
        s += d.strftime('%z')
        return s

In [8]: to_es_date(datetime.now())
Out[8]: '2014-04-30T03:56:02.893'

In [9]: to_es_date(datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc))
Out[9]: '2014-04-30T03:56:20.134+0000'
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import arrow

def timestamp(timestamp):
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp /  1_000_000.0)
    return formattdatetime(date)

def formattdatetime(date):
    date = arrow.get(date, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    return arrow.get(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

> These aren't 64bit timestamps, just regular (unix epoch) ones with millisecond resolution:

```
 import datetime
 datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1385942400000 / 1000.).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

> gives 2013-12-02

(thanks to @knutwalker's comment above)